# In what sense are loop diagrams quantum corrections?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, feynman-diagrams

What's so not-quantum about tree-level diagrams?

Comment: From the tag of the question, you are already assuming "FIELD" theory, are you? So the queston is how classical the fields are?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reasons were given [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27388/tree-level-qft-and-classical-fields-particles). Essentially, at tree level you recover classical results. Loop corrections are proportional to powers of $\hbar$ and these are quantum terms.

Comment: It is a bit more obscure for particles with spin, because then the classical result has still an $\hbar$.

Comment: That is right, but classically spin does not exist and so, the result is consistent.

Comment: Dead link in the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Tree level diagrams are one-particle relativistic quantum mechanics, but not quantum field theories.

The point is obscured by two reasonable details in modern QFT books: they avoid to speak of "2nd quantisation", and they set h=1 everywhere (so for instance it is not so clear how different the h->0 limit is for fermions than for scalar fields, or how bosons can add to build a classical electromagnetic field but fermions can not). It is expected that you go across a relativistic quantum mechanics textbook before jumping to QFT, but sometimes the career path is different.

Comment: There are relativistic quantum mechanics textbooks that are not quantum field theory texts?