# Loop counting -- what if the graph is not planar?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, graph-theory

It is typically claimed that $\hbar$ counts the number of loops in a connected diagram. E.g., Weinberg's QFT, Vol.II, equation 16.1.10. This rests on the fact that for a diagram with $I$ internal lines and $V$ vertices, the number of loops is
$$
L=I-V+1\tag1
$$

Now, this equation is essentially [Euler's formula for planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula). Such a formula is only valid for planar graphs though, so how do we make sense of $(1)$ for non-planar graphs? How do we prove $\hbar$ counts the number of loops in an arbitrary (connected) diagram, regardless of whether it is planar or not?

Comment: See the second part of [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176463/50583).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key point is that, as ACM points out in [this answer of his](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176463/84967), the formula for a general graph is just the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Relations_to_other_invariants):
$$
V-E+F=2(1-g)
$$
where $g$ is the [genus of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)#Graph_theory). Planar graphs are, by definition, those with $g=0$.

Planar or not, it is easy to see that the number of independent loops of an arbitrary graph is
$$
L=F-1+2g
$$
and therefore
$$
L=E-V+1
$$
independently of $g$.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

<sup>Note: the number of loops $L$ is $F-1$ (because the face "at infinity" is not counted as a loop) plus $2g$, because every handle allows you to add one cycle without intersections. Thus, $L=F-1+2g$, as claimed above.</sup>

Comment: Even if ACM's answer essentially answers my question, I don't really want to delete the post because [tag:thermodynamics] recently overtook [tag:quantum-field-theory] and I want the latter tag to get its position back. We need more QFT questions!