# How are tree-level calculations related to the classical theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I've read the answers (and linked notes) to another question ([Tree level QFT and classical fields/particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27388/tree-level-qft-and-classical-fields-particles)) and I understand them.  They seem to explain how to organise a perturbative calculation of the solution to a classical non-linear ODE by drawing diagrams which look a bit like Feynman diagrams.  But it is not clear to me how these diagrams correspond to *actual* Feynman diagrams.  In QFT, when Feynman diagrams are used when doing path integrals (to calculate correlation functions etc.) but not to solve for the fields.  What does the tree-level expansion of a correlation function mean and what is its classical interpretation?

Comment: The question (v2) (including the title question) seems to be essentially a duplicate of the [linked Phys.SE question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27388/2451).

Comment: The linked question has several answers, one of which is accepted, which don't answer this question (and arguably the other one). Perhaps that's because nobody knows the answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tree level QFT and classical fields/particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27388/)