# Recurrence relations for tree-level Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

Consider a certain quantum mechanical system with action $S[\phi]$, and let
$$
G(1,\dots,n)\equiv\langle\phi_1\cdots\phi_n\rangle
$$
be the $n$-point function. It is well-known that these functions satisfy a certain set of recurrence relations (cf. the Schwinger-Dyson equations) that allow us to write any $n$-point function as a combination of propagators and $n'$-point functions, for $n'=n,n+1,n+2,\dots$

The path integral of $S$ is the exponential generating functional of the sequence $\{G(1,\dots,n)\}$.

Let $G_t(1,\dots,n)$ be the tree-level contribution to the connected $n$-point function. The generating functional of these functions is the stationary-phase approximation to the path integral of $S$, and as such, I expect that there should exist a set of recurrence relations among them. In other words, we should be able to write any function $G_t(1,\dots,n)$ in terms of propagators and other functions $G_t(1,\dots,n')$. In fact, this is easily confirmed by calculating the first few tree-level $n$-point functions, which can always be written in terms of a finite series that involves propagators and vertices.

**Question:** What is the exact form of these recurrence relations? What is the analogous to the Schwinger-Dyson equations, but in terms of tree-level $n$ point functions instead of standard $n$-point functions?

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this yourself (eg computing tree level amplitudes and relating them)?

Comment: @JamalS I computed the first few (up to $n=4$) correlation functions, and checked that any of them could be written as linear combinations of the correlation functions of lower order. I couldn't come up with a general formula though.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform you could try substituting $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ in the ordinary $n$-point functions.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I tried to do that. The result is the same equations as in the Schwinger-Dyson equations but without the contact terms (those with Dirac deltas). That *seems* to work because, after all, contact terms are usually thought of as quantum corrections, so they should be absent in tree amplitudes. But it doesn't quite work: the resulting set of equations couple $n$-point functions to other functions with higher $n$ instead of lower $n$, which is what I expected (cf. my comment above). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus yes, that is precisely my point. The normal SD equation involve terms of higher order. The equations I am looking for involve terms of lower order. Thus, you cannot really derive the latter from the former.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform ah I see. Sorry about the confusion, but I think it is partially your fault. Could you explain really clearly which of these problems you are solving – (1) get a classical (tree-level) analogue of SD equations, (2) get a recursive relation with dependency only on lower-$n$ terms? I will delete my previous comments.

Comment: Btw is this what you're looking for? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27388/30833